# method chaining child with parent classes using c++

Tags: c++, templates, chaining, crtp, fluent-interface

Is there a way to chain calls to superclass from subclass without casting, overriding the method or using interfaces. E.g. when doing

```
class A {
public: 
    A& foo() { return *this; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B& bar() { return *this; }
};

int main(void) {
    B b;
    b.foo().bar();
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling with clang I'm getting the error

```
main.cpp:13:10: error: no member named 'bar' in 'A'
        b.foo().bar();
        ~~~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
```

Which I can see why (since A returns reference to self), but I would like it to return it's subclass type B since it is called in that context. Is this possible? Or do I need to define B as

```
class B : public A {
public:
    B& bar() { return *this; }
    B& foo() { A::foo(); return *this; }
};
```

and make foo() virtual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) pattern:

```
template<class Derived>
class A {
public:
    Derived& foo() { return *static_cast<Derived*>(this); }
};

class B : public A<B> {
public:
    B& bar() { return *this; }
};

int main(void) {
    B b;
    b.foo().bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but with that pattern I won't be able to instantiate an object of class A?

Comment: @Johan You can. Just inherit an empty class. `class just_a : public A<just_a> {};`